# Problem with numbering of references in chapters

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to different chapters, each with its own reference list. I partially managed to realize this, but I don't get the numbering of the second chapter correct. References that I used in chapter one, keep the same number in chapter two. I almost stared blind at this issue, so I really hope someone can help me out.

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,    
twoside=true,   
11pt,           
headings=normal     
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[        
backend= bibtex,        
bibencoding=utf8,
style=nature,   
sorting=none,
defernumbers=true,
refsegment=chapter,
natbib=true,
backref = false
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
    @misc{B02,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
    }
    @misc{C03,
        author = {Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Charlie},
    }
    @misc{D04,
        author = {Duthor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Delta},
    }
    @misc{E05,
        author = {Euthor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Ecko},
    }
    @misc{F06,
        author = {Futhor, C.},
        year = {2003},
        title = {Foxtrot},
    }   
\end{filecontents}
\addglobalbib{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{intro}
test \cite{A01} test \cite{B02} test \cite{C03} test \cite{D04}.
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,resetnumbers=true,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{chap2}
test \cite{E05} test \cite{B02} test \cite{A01} test \cite{F06}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,resetnumbers=true,heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use `chapterbib` package to have one cite section per chapter.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use **\RequirePackage** instead of the standard **\usepackage**?

Comment: I did not have a specific reason to use requirepackage instead of usepackage... I've changed that.

Comment: I have tried to implement the chapterbib package, but I dont know how to print only the references of the particular chapter, instead of the whole bibliography. How can I realize that with chapterbib?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

In order to have independent numbers for each chapter, you need to use a `refsection` instead of a `refsegment` (cf. [the `biblatex` manual, § 3.6.6](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsubsection.3.6.6)):

> The difference between a `refsection` and a `refsegment` environment is that the former creates labels which are local to the environment whereas the latter provides a target for the `segment` filter of `\printbibliography` without affecting the labels. They will be unique across the entire document.

So just change `refsegment=chapter` to `refsection=chapter` in your example to achieve the desired output.

Please note that when using BibTeX as a backend for `biblatex`, this approach creates multiple auxiliary files, one for each `refsection`, that need to be processed separately. So if your document is called `document.tex`, instead of `bibtex document` you need to execute `bibtex document1-blx`, `bibtex document2-blx`, ... (the log file includes a hint which commands you need to run). With the alternative backend [Biber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber), this is not necessary.

[image: page 1 of the example document]

[image: page 2 of the example document]

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I change to refsections, I lose unfortunately the reference lists. In the text appears: test [A01] test [B02] test [C03] test [D04].I've updated the code above, to include also some sample references. Do you have a clue what I do wrong?

Comment: @ArjenB Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to change the way you call BibTeX for this approach: you need to run a separate `bibtex` command for each `refsection`. I updated my answer accordingly, I hope this will make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Chapterbib](http://wiki.davidhaberthuer.ch/latex#chapterbib)

You will have to create a main file in which you `\include{}` your other .tex files, then place a bibliography in each included file:

```
\documentclass[
paper=A4,                   
twoside=true,               
11pt,
headings=normal
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\include{chapter_one}
\end{document}
```

Then in chapter_one.tex:

```
% Content of document
\bibliographystyle{style}
\bibliography{Mybibliography}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. unfortunately, i did not came a step further with the chapterbib approach...